# Log in for Google sheets for every member

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible that we can create a log in panel on google sheets which can be access by only shared person once they log in and after that they get the only tab which is shared with them instead of whole google spreadsheet
I heard it is possible but haven't seen somewhere ..!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a log sheet *"which can be access by only shared person once..."* and could **then** share by user.

Still.
It would not really serve your purpose since **anyone with editor privileges** will always have access to the history of the whole sheet (where one can easily see who edited what and when).

Comment: then is it possible to lock a cell range after a certain date or time in the sheet ???

Comment: That is a completely different issue. You should start a new question. But before that, please search for [relevant answers](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Google-Sheets+how+to+protect+a+cell+range+passed+a+date)