# LOCK column range at specific Date (month wise)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[LINK TO THE SAMPLE FILE HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ldrWEdHpFCQJ42Qu_dcKZlG4L4bcmqNUW9OYofebBoc/edit#gid=160973364) I have a spreadsheet which contains multiple tabs in it on which data is filled by multiple users at a time which go direct to my master-sheet through IMPORT-range Function but this create a problem for me as a user can change Data or value at any time which further will  reflect in master same which mean i have no control over the data as user can edit the values or the data according to the need.
**i want to lock the value for the columns at every 15th of the EACH [image: SAMPLE DATA IMAGE HERE]month**
AS you can see in the Image which shown each Tab have month wise column which is to be filled by the user
Any help would be appreciated
any suggestions to it ?

Comment: You can use a script for that. There are many answers to help you work it out.  Please [have a look](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+sheets+lock-range-at-specific-date+site:stackoverflow.com&newwindow=1). Give it a try.

Comment: A reminder.  
The answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73017953/log-in-for-google-sheets-for-every-member) was  

*"It would not really serve your purpose since anyone with editor
privileges will always have access to the history of the whole sheet
(where one can easily see who edited what and when)."*

Reading both your questions I think you should reconsider your "system".  Please let us know .

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you want to lock a column corresponding to the current month each 15th day of that month? And it would get unlocked on the 15th of the next month? Also, you want to do this on multiple tabs, which have the same structure? Does this apply to all tabs, or just to some? Also, are headers dates or strings? Please notice that the column will have to remain unprotected for at least one user (the one who executes the function that will protect the column). Finally, consider providing a copy of your spreadsheet in order to clarify most of the previous questions.

Comment: @Iamblichus i tried to explain in the sample sheet attached hereby, you almost got my concern i want no user can change the value of the column after 15th of the current month and that column should remains lock (no unlocking even after 15th )the sheet contains 6 tabs for now and out of which 2 tabs need to be ignore and the locking column is to be done with other 4 tabs (the headers remain the same in all 4 tabs) all 4 tabs are separately shared with 4 different users filling the data in the month column  (i hope you understand)

Comment: @marikamitsos I WANT TO LOCK the Column range in  4 different TABS in the a spreadsheet the script here is doing for a single spreadsheet with a single TAB would you please explain further ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue:

- To do this, you'll have to use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).
- A range cannot be protected for all users. At least the user executing user will still be able to edit this (this is not a feature of the solution proposed below; it's how Sheets work).

#### Solution:

- Create a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) that will fire the 15th of each month. This can be done [manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) or programmatically (by executing the function `installTrigger` below once, using [onMonthDay](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#onmonthdayday)). The triggered function (`protectCurrentMonthColumn` in the sample below) should do the following.
- Get the month index and year of the current date (see [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)).
- Get a list of sheets to protect (retrieve all sheets via [Spreadsheet.getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets) and filter out the ones to ignore) and iterate through them.
- For each sheet, get the column index of the header that contains current month date. You can compare `monthIndex` and `year` for that, and use [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to get the index.
- Using the `columnIndex`, get the corresponding [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) and [protect](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#protect) it.

#### Code sample:

```
function protectCurrentMonthColumn() {
  const SHEETS_TO_IGNORE = ["NDRX", "Verified NDRx"]; // Change according to your preferences
  const now = new Date();
  const monthIndex = now.getMonth(); // Current month
  const year = now.getFullYear(); // Current year
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheetsToProtect = ss.getSheets().filter(s => !SHEETS_TO_IGNORE.includes(s.getSheetName())); // Filter out ignored sheets
  sheetsToProtect.forEach(s => { // Iterate through sheets to protect
    const headers = s.getRange("1:1").getValues()[0];
    const columnIndex = headers.findIndex(header => { // Get index of the column to protect (header is current month and year)
      return typeof header.getMonth === 'function' && header.getMonth() === monthIndex && header.getFullYear() === year;
    });
    if (columnIndex > -1) { // If header is not found, don't protect anything
      const rangeToProtect = s.getRange(1,columnIndex+1,s.getLastRow()); // Column to protect
      const protection = rangeToProtect.protect();
      var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
      protection.addEditor(me);
      protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
      if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
        protection.setDomainEdit(false);
      }
    }
  });
}

function installTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("protectCurrentMonthColumn")
  .timeBased()
  .onMonthDay(15)
  .create();
}
```

#### Note:

- You have to execute `installTrigger` once for this to work.

Comment: DO i need to remove all the current protections of the sheet ???? and it will lock the column of current month as we are in july so i need to lock the previous months(april onwards) MANUALLY ?

Comment: @NischaySoni Yes, this will only protect the current month column (on day 15), it won't protect previous months (the function could be modified to protect all previous months programmatically, but this modified function shouldn't run via trigger). About whether current protections need to be removed, it depends on what you want (this won't remove any protection, but just add the one corresponding to current month).

Comment: @lamblichus i tried the script after changing the day 15 to 20 and executed the script but the user with editor right is still able to edit in the current month column

Comment: @NischaySoni Sorry there was a typo (basically `getValues()` should be replaced by `getValues()[0]`, but also the column index should be adapted since ranges are 1-based, not 0-based). That's what happens when one doesn't test the script before posting it. Most importantly, in order to test this on the spot, execute `protectCurrentMonthColumn`, not `installTrigger`. `installTrigger` will only cause `protectCurrentMonthColumn` (the function which is actually doing the job) to execute at some time during the month day (be it 15 or 20), so it won't happen immediately.

Comment: @NischaySoni Also very important, every time you execute `installTrigger` a new trigger is installed, so you might end up with many duplicate triggers (and very possibly duplicate sheet protections). To remove the duplicates, visit the `Triggers` tab and remove them. In any case, I updated the script from my answer and tested it on my side, it's working for me. I hope it works for you now too.

Comment: @lamblichus the script runs fine now ,thank you so much for the gesture , i really appreciate it ,I am new to App Script and not much familiar APP SCRIPT function. I know you're already a immortal ,Please accept my apology for a poor skills. thanks alot (you ALREADY have my respect<3).

Comment: Sorry but I am confused. So this question goes to both lamblichus and @NischaySoni as well. You mention *" a **spreadsheet** which contains multiple tabs in it on which data is **filled by multiple users** at a time which **go direct to my master-sheet** through IMPORT-range Function"*. Could you please clarify if this spreadsheet `Copy os A21` is the sheet that everyone writes to **OR** is it the spreadsheet which data is imported to (from other various spreadsheets)? Please clarify. **Is this `Copy of A21` the master-sheet? Yes OR No?**

Comment: @marikamitsos ITS a sample file IN which data is filled by the users >>>>NOT MY MASTER FILE

Comment: In that case, have you considered the fact that since they are **editors** (they have to be in order to  be able to fill-in their specific range), they **will also have access to the script itself** of the non-test sheet? Have you tried the proposed solution using a different account with editor access to the spreadsheet?

Comment: @marikamitsos If he's worried about editors having access to that script, he could use a [standalone script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) instead. In this case, he'd just need to replace `const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();` with `const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET_ID");`.

Comment: @marikamitsos I tried it with the different account having the editor RIGHTS here & it limit the users to edit it after a specific date mentioned in the script itself And yes STANDALONE script does the rest of the work here

Comment: Great. Standalone does the trick of completely protecting your sheet. The other option I was thinking was using a script on your master. Just a thought.

Comment: @lamblichus I hadn't thought of the standalone script. Well-thought. Thank you.